# Video file is inverted. Can it be fixed?

Tags: video

I just got a video file in my email that we want to use on our website.  However, the entire thing is inverted so the people are walking on the ceiling.  Is there any software that I can use to reverse this?  The file is a .mov if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

Use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). It's the swiss army knife for video converting/editing.  Once it's installed, enter the following command on the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf "vflip" output.mov
```

Look at following answer: https://superuser.com/questions/578321/how-to-flip-a-video-180-vertical-upside-down-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can flip your video online on [video rotate](http://videorotate.com) if you don't want to install anything.
Just drag video to upload , choose orientation and download.